# How can I add new location to a button?

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, layout-manager

The button I made is named from a `String` but I can't enter its location.

```
f.add(new JButton(btn).setBounds(10,10,10,10));
```

Comment: You typically use [layout managers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) to place widgets (labels, input fields, buttons) in a container (frame).

Comment: 1) `f.add(new JButton(btn).setBounds(10,10,10,10));` I'm surprised that even compiles. 2) A good way to center a component within its parent container is to add it as the only component of a `GridBagLayout`. It removes all guesswork, and dynamically adjusts the location as the window is resized by the user.

Comment: If you must set bounds: `JButton b=JButton(btn); b.setBounds(10,10,10,10));  f.add(b);`

Comment: I don't think I could explain it to you
I meant this code:

Comment: btn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
                    int a = 6;
                    for (int i=1; i<=a; ++i)
                    {
                        ++a;
                        frame.add(new JButton(String.valueOf("btn"+a)));
                    }

                }
            });

Comment: *"explain it to you"* You .. who? Who are you replying to? 1) Tip: Add @gogognome (or whoever, the `@` is important) to *notify* the person of a new comment. 2) Provide ASCII art or a simple drawing of the *intended* layout of the GUI at minimum size, and if resizable, with more width and height - to show how the extra space should be used. 3) For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Answer (score 0):

To control absulotely the location and size of your components, you need to set the `LayoutManager` to null, for example: `jframe.setLayout(null);` and set their bounds with `setBounds(x, y, width, height)` method.

Comment: From the horse's mouth (so to speak). Excerpts from [Doing Without a Layout Manager (Absolute Positioning)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/none.html): _Although it is possible to do without a layout manager, you should use a layout manager if at all possible._ ... _If a container holds components whose size is not affected by the container's size or by font, look-and-feel, or language changes, then absolute positioning might make sense._